# Confusing defcustom usage in info.el

Tags: customize, start-up, info, autoload

I was trying to read the [info.el](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/info.el) code when I ran across this strange use of `defcustom`:

```el
;; This is a defcustom largely so that we can get the benefit
;; of custom-initialize-delay.  Perhaps it would work to make it a
;; defvar and explicitly give it a standard-value property, and
;; call custom-initialize-delay on it.
;; The progn forces the autoloader to include the whole thing, not
;; just an abbreviated version.  The value is initialized at startup
;; time, when command-line calls custom-reevaluate-setting on all
;; the defcustoms in custom-delayed-init-variables.  This is
;; somewhat sub-optimal, as ideally this should be done when Info
;; mode is first invoked.
;;;###autoload
(progn
(defcustom Info-default-directory-list
  (let* ((config-dir
      (file-name-as-directory
       ;; Self-contained NS build with info/ in the app-bundle.
       (or (and (featurep 'ns)
            (let ((dir (expand-file-name "../info" data-directory)))
              (if (file-directory-p dir) dir)))
           configure-info-directory)))
     (prefixes
      ;; Directory trees in which to look for info subdirectories
      (prune-directory-list '("/usr/local/" "/usr/" "/opt/")))
     (suffixes
      ;; Subdirectories in each directory tree that may contain info
      ;; directories.
      '("share/" ""))
     (standard-info-dirs
      (apply #'nconc
         (mapcar (lambda (pfx)
               (let ((dirs
                  (mapcar (lambda (sfx)
                        (concat pfx sfx "info/"))
                      suffixes)))
                 (prune-directory-list dirs)))
             prefixes)))
     ;; If $(prefix)/share/info is not one of the standard info
     ;; directories, they are probably installing an experimental
     ;; version of Emacs, so make sure that experimental version's Info
     ;; files override the ones in standard directories.
     (dirs
      (if (member config-dir standard-info-dirs)
          ;; FIXME?  What is the point of adding it again at the end
          ;; when it is already present earlier in the list?
          (nconc standard-info-dirs (list config-dir))
        (cons config-dir standard-info-dirs))))
    (if (not (eq system-type 'windows-nt))
    dirs
      ;; Include the info directory near where Emacs executable was installed.
      (let* ((instdir (file-name-directory invocation-directory))
         (dir1 (expand-file-name "../info/" instdir))
         (dir2 (expand-file-name "../../../info/" instdir)))
    (cond ((file-exists-p dir1) (append dirs (list dir1)))
          ((file-exists-p dir2) (append dirs (list dir2)))
          (t dirs)))))

  "Default list of directories to search for Info documentation files.
They are searched in the order they are given in the list.
Therefore, the directory of Info files that come with Emacs
normally should come last (so that local files override standard ones),
unless Emacs is installed into a non-standard directory.  In the latter
case, the directory of Info files that come with Emacs should be
first in this list.

Once Info is started, the list of directories to search
comes from the variable `Info-directory-list'.
This variable `Info-default-directory-list' is used as the default
for initializing `Info-directory-list' when Info is started, unless
the environment variable INFOPATH is set.

Although this is a customizable variable, that is mainly for technical
reasons.  Normally, you should either set INFOPATH or customize
`Info-additional-directory-list', rather than changing this variable."
  :initialize 'custom-initialize-delay
  :type '(repeat directory)
  :group 'info))
```

There is a blurb before this code explaining why it's wrapped in a `progn`, but it would be nice to hear it translated into plain English. Also, the fact that a huge `let*` comes next is boggling for this beginner. The [reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Variable-Definitions.html) isn't very helpful for beginners either. And the beginner manual gives a very simple `defcustom` example which is no help here. Can someone tell me the whys and wheretofors of this particular `defcustom`? I'm basically trying to track down -- for didactical purposes -- how Emacs populates its `Info-directory-list` variable.

Comment: There are several different things discussed in that complex code comment, which touches on Emacs startup, autoload, and the Customize system. So the question, which is essentially asking to explain everything in that code comment, is really too broad for SE. I think it can remain open, and folks can usefully explain/describe all or parts of the code comment in answers. But this is not really a question about how to do something - not a very good fit for SE.emacs, IMO.

Comment: I'm mostly curious about what the `let*` is doing in the middle of a supposed macro `defcustom`. According to the Emacs Lisp manual `defcustom` has fields that take "normal" things, not entire `let*` blocks. If this could be explained, I'll shut up and sit down.

Comment: Every form in Elisp (and other lisps) evaluates to an expression, i.e. a value. Forms can be arbitrarily complex, ranging from simple self-evaluating atoms like the numbers `1` and `2` to nested expressions like `(let ((x 1) (y 2)) (+ x y))`. As Drew explains, `defcustom` evaluates its second argument so, for example, it doesn't matter whether you give it `3` or the `let` expression I just wrote - the resultant value passed to `defcustom` is the same.

Comment: In other words, the fact that `defcustom` evaluates its second argument (i.e. recursively reduces it until it can be reduced no further according to the semantics of the language) means that a big fat expression like the one you quote is no less "normal" a thing than a simple one and it makes `defcustom` no less of a macro. If you are still a bit confused by lisp evaluation I highly recommend reading the first chapter of [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html) (or all of it if you find the time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Responding to your last comment, asking about the `let*`. Putting this into an answer so the doc-string can be clear.

The `let*` sexp is simply evaluated when the `defcustom` is read (e.g. the file is loaded), and its return value is used as the initial value of the user option (variable). `C-h f defcustom` tells you that.  It says this about the second argument to `defcustom`, `STANDARD`:

> `STANDARD` is an expression specifying the variable’s standard
>   value.  It should not be quoted.  It is evaluated once by
>   `defcustom`, and the value is assigned to `SYMBOL` if the variable
>   is unbound.

So `(defcustom foo fill-column "..." ...)` evaluates the sexp `fill-column` to get its value (e.g. `70`), and that value becomes the initial value of option `foo` (if `foo` does not already have a value).

In this case, the sexp that is evaluated to get the initial value for option `Info-default-directory-list` is a `let*` expression: `(let* (...)...)`.  That's all.

Comment: Beginners are typically neurotic and angst-ridden. I guessed what you just said to be the case, but it just seems so weird that I had to check with the wiser, more-experienced. I've come to realize the `let` is a mysterious thing in the functional world. If anyone knows of a good learning source that really goes into depth on the uses of `let`, er, let me know.

Comment: It's hard to know what about `let` is unclear to you. I assume you've already started with the Elisp manual, node [Local Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Local-Variables.html). The Intro to Elisp manual, node [Sample let Expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Sample-let-Expression.html) might also help. Or perhaps Common Lisp The Language, section about [`let` and `let*`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw60/CLHS/Body/s_let_l.htm).

Comment: Not beginner syntax, but real-world uses -- such as in the OP. There's a huge gap between the `let*` in the OP and your beginner links. I guess my best path is to continue hunting crazy `let`s (and other far beyond beginner's manual things) in the wild and then ask about them here -- get what flak I may.

Comment: @147pm Sorry to burst your bubble, but `let`/`let*`/`letrec` are extremely common, fundamental and un-mysterious constructs not only in Elisp but in both other lisps and languages as well (though they obviously don't share equivalent semantics). Constructs like these do not in and of themselves comprise complexity; the complexity arises from how they are used in the program, in the same way that there is nothing mysterious about `if`, `while` and `;` in C and yet the Structured Program Theorem says they (roughly speaking) can compute every computable function.

Comment: @147pm Just to be clear, Elisp and some other lisps are far from being functional programming languages; perhaps you meant expression-oriented or similar. If you are curious about `let` expressions in their more formal sense, then Emacs SE is not the right forum; perhaps try the Computer Science SE or similar instead.

Comment: @Basil: Maybe you guys should consider moving your discussion to chat?

Comment: @Drew I'd be happy to, sorry about the noise. Feel free to move my comments there if you have the ability to.

Comment: @basil: I don't know how to do that. I think that if you guys want to continue discussing you can just carry on over there. Dunno more about it - I never use the chat.